# My Swing application is not appearing properly any more

Tags: java, swing, calculator

I developped a Java Calculator using Swing. I have so many buttons and JLabels and other compenents.
Before when I run my program it was showing correctly. After it is not appearing properly and I always have to close the application's window and run it again and again many times until it is showing.

This is what I get :

[image]

In addition, I dont have any errors or exceptions. What is the reason of this issue?

The code :

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.Border;

import org.jdesktop.swingx.JXDatePicker;

import net.sourceforge.jdatepicker.impl.JDatePanelImpl;
import net.sourceforge.jdatepicker.impl.JDatePickerImpl;
import net.sourceforge.jdatepicker.impl.UtilDateModel;

public class Calculette extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;



    Border cadre = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("");
    //Les panneaux
    JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
    JPanel panel2= new JPanel();
    JPanel panel3 = new JPanel();

    //les menus
    JMenuBar menubar = new JMenuBar();
    JMenu fichier = new JMenu("Fichier");
    JMenu edition = new JMenu("Edition");
    JMenu help = new JMenu("?");
    JMenuItem fermer = new JMenuItem("Fermer");
    JMenuItem copier = new JMenuItem("Copier");
    JMenuItem coller = new JMenuItem("Coller");
    JMenuItem apropos = new JMenuItem("A propos de la calculatrice");
    JLabel jlab1 = new JLabel("Selectionnez un type de calcul sur les dates :");
    JComboBox<String> list = new JComboBox<String>();
    GridBagLayout gbl = new GridBagLayout();
    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    BorderLayout borderl = new BorderLayout(); 
    public JTextArea resultat = new JTextArea(2,35);
    ButtonGroup bg = new ButtonGroup();
    JRadioButton degres = new JRadioButton("Degrés");
    JRadioButton radians = new JRadioButton("Radians");
    JRadioButton grades = new JRadioButton("Grades");
    JButton mc = new JButton ("MC");
    JButton mr = new JButton ("MR");
    JButton ms = new JButton ("MS");
    JButton mpls = new JButton ("M+");
    JButton mmns = new JButton ("M-");

    JButton vide = new JButton("");
    JButton inv = new JButton("Inv");
    JButton ln = new JButton("ln");
    JButton pranthese1 = new JButton("(");
    JButton pranthese2 = new JButton(")");


    JButton efface = new JButton("\u2190");
    JButton ce = new JButton("CE");
    JButton c = new JButton("C");
    JButton plusmoins = new JButton(" ±");
    JButton carre = new JButton("√");

    JButton intt = new JButton("Int");
    JButton sinh = new JButton("sinh");
    JButton sin = new JButton("sin");
    JButton xcarre = new JButton("x²");
    JButton nfact = new JButton("n!");

    JButton b7 = new JButton("7");
    JButton b8 = new JButton("8");
    JButton b9 = new JButton("9");
    JButton slash = new JButton("/");
    JButton percent = new JButton("%");

    JButton dms = new JButton("dms");
    JButton cosh = new JButton("cosh");
    JButton cos = new JButton("cos");
    JButton xpowery = new JButton("<html>x<sup>y</sup></html>");
    JButton ycarrex = new JButton("y√x");

    JButton b4 = new JButton("4");
    JButton b5 = new JButton("5");
    JButton b6 = new JButton("6");
    JButton etoil = new JButton("*");
    JButton unsurx = new JButton("1/x");

    JButton pi = new JButton("π");
    JButton tanh = new JButton("tanh");
    JButton tan = new JButton("tan");
    JButton xpowertr = new JButton("x³");
    JButton carrecubx = new JButton("∛x");

    JButton b1 = new JButton("1");
    JButton b2 = new JButton("2");
    JButton b3 = new JButton("3");
    JButton moins = new JButton("-");
    JButton egal = new JButton("=");

    JButton fe = new JButton("F-E");
    JButton exp = new JButton("Exp");
    JButton mod = new JButton("Mod");
    JButton log = new JButton("log");
    JButton dixy = new JButton("<html>10<sup>x</sup></html>");

    public JButton b0 = new JButton("0");
    JButton virgule = new JButton(",");
    JButton plus = new JButton("+");

    //deuxieme panel
    JLabel de = new JLabel("de");
    JLabel a = new JLabel("a");


    JXDatePicker datePicker1 = new JXDatePicker();
    JXDatePicker datePicker2 = new JXDatePicker();
    JXDatePicker datePicker3 = new JXDatePicker();


    JLabel labdiff = new JLabel("Différence (années, mois, semaines, jours)");
    public JTextField textdif = new JTextField(40);
    JLabel labdiffj = new JLabel("Différence (jours)");
    public JTextField textdifj = new JTextField(40);

    JLabel dee = new JLabel("De");
    ButtonGroup btg = new ButtonGroup();
    JRadioButton ajout = new JRadioButton("Ajouter");
    JRadioButton soustr = new JRadioButton("Soustraire");
    JLabel an = new JLabel("Année(s)");
    JLabel mois = new JLabel("Mois");
    JLabel jour = new JLabel("Jour(s)");

    SpinnerModel spinnerModel = new SpinnerNumberModel(0,0,999,1);
    SpinnerModel spinnerModel2 = new SpinnerNumberModel(0,0,999,1);
    SpinnerModel spinnerModel3 = new SpinnerNumberModel(0,0,999,1);

    JSpinner anlist = new JSpinner(spinnerModel);
    JSpinner moilist = new JSpinner(spinnerModel2);
    JSpinner jourlist = new JSpinner(spinnerModel3);

    JLabel datee = new JLabel("Date");
    JTextField textdate = new JTextField(40);
    public JButton calcul1 = new JButton("Calculer");

    public JButton calculer = new JButton("Calculer");

    ////
    Font f = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 10);
    JButton frac = new JButton("Frac");
    JButton ex = new JButton("<html>e<sup>x</sup></html>");
    JButton sinhun = new JButton("<html>sinh<sup>-1</sup></html>");
    JButton sinmun = new JButton("<html>sin<sup>-1</sup></html>");
    JButton deg = new JButton("deg");
    JButton coshun = new JButton("<html>cosh<sup>-1</sup></html>");
    JButton cosun = new JButton("<html>cos<sup>-1</sup></html>");
    JButton deuxpi = new JButton("2*π");
    JButton tanhun = new JButton("<html>tanh<sup>-1</sup></html>");
    JButton tanun = new JButton("<html>tan<sup>-1</sup></html>");
    ////
    int first=1;  double result=0,memory=0,n1=0;
    double num;  int opt=2; int oper1=0,oper2=0;

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public Calculette(){

        super("Calculatrice");
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setSize(1100, 320);
        this.getContentPane().add(panel1);
        panel1.setLayout(borderl);
        panel1.add(panel2,BorderLayout.WEST);
        panel1.add(panel3,BorderLayout.EAST);
        panel3.setBackground(Color.WHITE); 
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.setJMenuBar(menubar);
        menubar.add(fichier);
        menubar.add(edition);
        menubar.add(help);
        fichier.add(fermer);
        edition.add(copier);
        edition.add(coller);
        help.add(apropos);
        copier.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_C,Event.CTRL_MASK,true));
        coller.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_V,Event.CTRL_MASK,true));
        list.addItem("Calculer la différence entre deux dates");
        list.addItem("Ajouter ou soustraire des jours à une date spécifiée");
        list.setSize(20, 10);
        panel2.setBorder(cadre);
        panel3.setBorder(cadre); 
        resultat.setBorder(cadre);
        panel2.setLayout(gbl);
        panel3.setLayout(gbl);
        btg.add(ajout); btg.add(soustr); 
        ajout.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        soustr.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        datePicker1.setDate(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
        datePicker1.setFormats(new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy"));
        datePicker2.setDate(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
        datePicker2.setFormats(new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy"));
        datePicker3.setDate(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
        datePicker3.setFormats(new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy"));

        coordonne(0,0,gbc,10,1);
        panel2.add(resultat,gbc);
        resultat.setEditable(false);
        bg.add(degres); bg.add(radians); bg.add(grades);
        vide.setEnabled(false);
        textdif.setEditable(false);
        textdifj.setEditable(false);
        textdate.setEditable(false);

        coordonne(0,1,gbc,1,1);
        panel2.add(degres,gbc);

        coordonne(1,1,gbc,1,1);
        panel2.add(radians,gbc);

        coordonne(2,1,gbc,3,1);
        panel2.add(grades,gbc);

        coordonne(5,1,gbc,1,1);
        panel2.add(mc,gbc);

        coordonne(6,1,gbc,1,1);
        panel2.add(mr,gbc);

        coordonne(7,1,gbc,1,1);
        panel2.add(ms,gbc);

        coordonne(8,1,gbc,1,1);
        panel2.add(mpls,gbc);

        coordonne(9,1,gbc,1,1);
        panel2.add(mmns,gbc);

        coordonne(0,2,gbc,1,1);
        panel2.add(vide,gbc);

        coordonne(1,2,gbc,1,1);
        panel2.add(inv,gbc);

        coordonne(2,2,gbc,1,1);
        panel2.add(ln,gbc);

        coordonne(3,2,gbc,1,1);
        panel2.add(pranthese1,gbc);

        coordonne(4,2,gbc,1,1);
        panel2.add(pranthese2,gbc);

        coordonne(5,2,gbc,1,1);
        panel2.add(efface,gbc);

        coordonne(6,2,gbc,1,1);
        panel2.add(ce,gbc);

        coordonne(7,2,gbc,1,1);
        panel2.add(c,gbc);

        coordonne(8,2,gbc,1,1);
        panel2.add(plusmoins,gbc);

        coordonne(9,2,gbc,1,1);
        panel2.add(carre,gbc);

        coordonne(0,3,gbc,1,1);
        panel2.add(intt,gbc);

        coordonne(1,3,gbc,1,1);
        panel2.add(sinh,gbc);

        coordonne(2,3,gbc,1,1);
        panel2.add(sin,gbc);

        coordonne(3,3,gbc,1,1);
        panel2.add(xcarre,gbc);

        coordonne(4,3,gbc,1,1);
        panel2.add(nfact,gbc);

        coordonne(5,3,gbc,1,1);
        panel2.add(b7,gbc);

        coordonne(6,3,gbc,1,1);
        panel2.add(b8,gbc);

        coordonne(7,3,gbc,1,1);
        panel2.add(b9,gbc);

        coordonne(8,3,gbc,1,1);
        panel2.add(slash,gbc);

        coordonne(9,3,gbc,1,1);
        panel2.add(percent,gbc);

        coordonne(0,4,gbc,1,1);
        panel2.add(dms,gbc);

        coordonne(1,4,gbc,1,1);
        panel2.add(cosh,gbc);

        coordonne(2,4,gbc,1,1);
        panel2.add(cos,gbc);

        coordonne(3,4,gbc,1,1);
        panel2.add(xpowery,gbc);

        coordonne(4,4,gbc,1,1);
        panel2.add(ycarrex,gbc);

        coordonne(5,4,gbc,1,1);
        panel2.add(b4,gbc);

        coordonne(6,4,gbc,1,1);
        panel2.add(b5,gbc);

        coordonne(7,4,gbc,1,1);
        panel2.add(b6,gbc);

        coordonne(8,4,gbc,1,1);
        panel2.add(etoil,gbc);

        coordonne(9,4,gbc,1,1);
        panel2.add(unsurx,gbc);

        coordonne(0,5,gbc,1,1);
        panel2.add(pi,gbc);

        coordonne(1,5,gbc,1,1);
        panel2.add(tanh,gbc);

        coordonne(2,5,gbc,1,1);
        panel2.add(tan,gbc);

        coordonne(3,5,gbc,1,1);
        panel2.add(xpowertr,gbc);

        coordonne(4,5,gbc,1,1);
        panel2.add(carrecubx,gbc);

        coordonne(5,5,gbc,1,1);
        panel2.add(b1,gbc);

        coordonne(6,5,gbc,1,1);
        panel2.add(b2,gbc);

        coordonne(7,5,gbc,1,1);
        panel2.add(b3,gbc);

        coordonne(8,5,gbc,1,1);
        panel2.add(moins,gbc);

        coordonne(9,5,gbc,1,2);
        panel2.add(egal,gbc);

        coordonne(0,6,gbc,1,1);
        panel2.add(fe,gbc);

        coordonne(1,6,gbc,1,1);
        panel2.add(exp,gbc);

        coordonne(2,6,gbc,1,1);
        panel2.add(mod,gbc);

        coordonne(3,6,gbc,1,1);
        panel2.add(log,gbc);

        coordonne(4,6,gbc,1,1);
        panel2.add(dixy,gbc);

        coordonne(5,6,gbc,2,1);
        panel2.add(b0,gbc);

        coordonne(7,6,gbc,1,1);
        panel2.add(virgule,gbc);

        coordonne(8,6,gbc,1,1);
        panel2.add(plus,gbc);


        coordonne(0,0,gbc,6,1);
        panel3.add(jlab1,gbc);

        coordonne(0,1,gbc,6,1);
        panel3.add(list,gbc);
        ////////////////////////
        coordonne(0,2,gbc,2,1);
        panel3.add(de,gbc);

        coordonne(2,2,gbc,1,1);
        panel3.add(datePicker1,gbc);

        coordonne(3,2,gbc,2,1);
        panel3.add(a,gbc);

        coordonne(5,2,gbc,1,1);
        panel3.add(datePicker2,gbc);

        coordonne(0,3,gbc,6,1);
        panel3.add(labdiff,gbc);

        coordonne(0,4,gbc,6,1);
        panel3.add(textdif,gbc);

        coordonne(0,5,gbc,6,1);
        panel3.add(labdiffj,gbc);

        coordonne(0,6,gbc,6,1);
        panel3.add(textdifj,gbc);

        coordonne(5,7,gbc,1,1);
        panel3.add(calculer,gbc);








        //Evenement basics
        list.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

                if (list.getSelectedIndex()==0 ){

                    panel3.remove(dee); 
                    panel3.validate();
                    panel3.remove(datePicker3); 
                    panel3.validate();
                    panel3.remove(ajout); 
                    panel3.validate();
                    panel3.remove(soustr); 
                    panel3.validate();
                    panel3.remove(an);
                    panel3.validate();
                    panel3.remove(anlist);
                    panel3.validate();
                    panel3.remove(mois);
                    panel3.validate();
                    panel3.remove(moilist);
                    panel3.validate();
                    panel3.remove(jour);
                    panel3.validate();
                    panel3.remove(jourlist);
                    panel3.validate();
                    panel3.remove(datee); 
                    panel3.validate();
                    panel3.remove(textdate);
                    panel3.validate();
                    panel3.remove(calcul1);
                    panel3.validate();
                    ///////////
                    coordonne(0,2,gbc,2,1);
                    panel3.add(de,gbc);

                    coordonne(2,2,gbc,1,1);
                    panel3.add(datePicker1,gbc);

                    coordonne(3,2,gbc,2,1);
                    panel3.add(a,gbc);

                    coordonne(5,2,gbc,1,1);
                    panel3.add(datePicker2,gbc);

                    coordonne(0,3,gbc,6,1);
                    panel3.add(labdiff,gbc);

                    coordonne(0,4,gbc,6,1);
                    panel3.add(textdif,gbc);

                    coordonne(0,5,gbc,6,1);
                    panel3.add(labdiffj,gbc);

                    coordonne(0,6,gbc,6,1);
                    panel3.add(textdifj,gbc);

                    coordonne(5,7,gbc,1,1);
                    panel3.add(calculer,gbc);

                    panel3.validate();      
                }

                if( list.getSelectedIndex()==1){

                    panel3.remove(de);
                    panel3.validate();
                    panel3.remove(datePicker1);
                    panel3.validate();
                    panel3.remove(a);
                    panel3.validate();
                    panel3.remove(datePicker2);
                    panel3.validate();
                    panel3.remove(labdiff);
                    panel3.validate();
                    panel3.remove(textdif);
                    panel3.validate();
                    panel3.remove(labdiffj);
                    panel3.validate();
                    panel3.remove(textdifj);
                    panel3.validate();
                    panel3.remove(calculer);
                    panel3.validate();                  

                    /////////

                    coordonne(0,2,gbc,1,1);
                    panel3.add(dee,gbc); 

                    coordonne(2,2,gbc,2,1);
                    panel3.add(datePicker3,gbc); 

                    coordonne(4,2,gbc,1,1);
                    panel3.add(ajout,gbc); 

                    coordonne(5,2,gbc,2,1);
                    panel3.add(soustr,gbc); 

                    coordonne(0,3,gbc,1,1);
                    panel3.add(an,gbc);

                    coordonne(1,3,gbc,1,1);
                    panel3.add(anlist,gbc);

                    coordonne(2,3,gbc,1,1);
                    panel3.add(mois,gbc);

                    coordonne(3,3,gbc,1,1);
                    panel3.add(moilist,gbc);

                    coordonne(4,3,gbc,1,1);
                    panel3.add(jour,gbc);

                    coordonne(5,3,gbc,1,1);
                    panel3.add(jourlist,gbc);

                    coordonne(0,4,gbc,6,1);
                    panel3.add(datee,gbc);

                    coordonne(0,5,gbc,6,1);
                    panel3.add(textdate,gbc);

                    coordonne(5,6,gbc,1,1);
                    panel3.add(calcul1,gbc);
                    panel3.validate();
                }
            }
        });

        inv.addActionListener(this);
        final JButton[] tab_button = {b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6, b7, b8, b9, b0,c,ce,calcul1,calculer,carre,carrecubx,cos,plus,moins,slash,etoil,egal,mc,mmns,mpls,efface,unsurx,plusmoins};

        for(int i = 0; i < tab_button.length; i++)
        {
            tab_button[i].addActionListener(this);
        }

        final JMenuItem[] tab_items = {apropos,coller,copier,fermer};
        for(int i = 0; i < tab_items.length; i++)
        {
            tab_items[i].addActionListener(this);
        }

    }


    public static void coordonne(int x, int y, GridBagConstraints g,int gw,int gh){
        g.gridx= x;
        g.gridy= y ;
        g.insets=new Insets(2,2,2,2);
        g.gridwidth = gw;
        g.gridheight = gh;
        g.fill=GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    } 



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Calculette();
    }


    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        String str;
        //Action Corresponding to + button
        if(e.getSource()==plus)
        {
            if(first==1)
            {
                result=num=Double.parseDouble(resultat.getText());
                oper1=1;
            }
            else
            {
                n1=Double.parseDouble(resultat.getText());
                oper2=1;
            }
            //Action corresponding to previous operator
            switch(oper1)
            {
            case 1:add1();
            break;
            case 2:sub();
            break;
            case 3:div();
            break;
            case 4:mul();
            break;
            }
        }
        //Action Corresponding to * button
        if(e.getSource()==etoil)
        {
            if(first==1)
            {
                result=num=Double.parseDouble(resultat.getText());
                oper1=4;
            }
            else
            {
                n1=Double.parseDouble(resultat.getText());
                oper2=4;
            }
            //Action corresponding to previous operator
            switch(oper1)
            {
            case 1:add1();
            break;
            case 2:sub();
            break;
            case 3:div();
            break;
            case 4:mul();
            break;
            }
        }
        //Action Corresponding to / button
        if(e.getSource()==slash)
        {
            if(first==1)
            {
                result=num=Double.parseDouble(resultat.getText());
                oper1=3;
            }
            else
            {
                n1=Double.parseDouble(resultat.getText());
                oper2=3;
            }
            //Action corresponding to previous operator
            switch(oper1)
            {
            case 1:add1();
            break;
            case 2:sub();
            break;
            case 3:div();
            break;
            case 4:mul();
            break;
            }
        }
        //Action Corresponding to - button
        else if(e.getSource()==moins)
        {
            if(first==1)
            {
                result=num=Double.parseDouble(resultat.getText());
                oper1=2;
            }
            else
            {
                n1=Double.parseDouble(resultat.getText());
                oper2=2;
            }
            //Action corresponding to previous operator
            switch(oper1)
            {
            case 1:add1();
            break;
            case 2:sub();
            break;
            case 3:div();
            break;
            case 4:mul();
            break;
            }

        }
        //Action Corresponding to = button
        else if(e.getSource()==egal)
        {
            double n1=Double.parseDouble(resultat.getText());
            if(oper1==1)
                result=result+n1;
            else if(oper1==2)
                result=result-n1;
            else if(oper1==3)
                result=result/n1;
            else if(oper1==4)
                result=result*n1;
            else
                result=Double.parseDouble(resultat.getText());
            num=result;
            str=String.valueOf(result);
            resultat.setText(str);
        }
        //Action Corresponding to MS button
        else if(e.getSource()==ms)
        {
            memory=Double.parseDouble(resultat.getText());
            str=String.valueOf("M");


        }
        //Action Corresponding to M button
        else if(e.getSource()==mpls)
        {
            memory=memory+Double.parseDouble(resultat.getText());
        }
        //Action Corresponding to MC button
        else if(e.getSource()==mc)
        {
            memory=0;
            resultat.setText("0");

        }
        //Action Corresponding to MR button
        else if(e.getSource()==mr)
        {
            str=String.valueOf(memory);
            resultat.setText(str);
        }
        //Action Corresponding to +/- button
        else if(e.getSource()==plusmoins)
        {
            double n1=Double.parseDouble(resultat.getText());
            n1=-n1;
            str=String.valueOf(n1);
            resultat.setText(str);
        }
        //Action Corresponding to 0 button
        else if(e.getSource()==b0)
        {
            if(opt==1)
                str=String.valueOf(resultat.getText())+0;
            else
                str=String.valueOf(" ")+0;
            opt=1;
            resultat.setText(str);  

        }
        //Action Corresponding to 1 button
        else if(e.getSource()==b1)
        {
            if(opt==1)
                str=String.valueOf(resultat.getText())+1;
            else
                str=String.valueOf(" ")+1;
            opt=1;
            resultat.setText(str);

        }
        //Action Corresponding to 2 button
        else if(e.getSource()==b2)
        {
            if(opt==1)
                str=String.valueOf(resultat.getText())+2;
            else
                str=String.valueOf(" ")+2;
            opt=1;
            resultat.setText(str);
        }
        //Action Corresponding to 3 button
        else if(e.getSource()==b3)
        {
            if(opt==1)
                str=String.valueOf(resultat.getText())+3;
            else
                str=String.valueOf(" ")+3;
            opt=1;
            resultat.setText(str);
        }
        //Action Corresponding to 4 button
        else if(e.getSource()==b4)
        {
            if(opt==1)
                str=String.valueOf(resultat.getText())+4;
            else
                str=String.valueOf(" ")+4;
            opt=1;
            resultat.setText(str);
        }
        //Action Corresponding to 5 button
        else if(e.getSource()==b5)
        {
            if(opt==1)
                str=String.valueOf(resultat.getText())+5;
            else
                str=String.valueOf(" ")+5;
            opt=1;
            resultat.setText(str);
        }
        //Action Corresponding to 6 button
        else if(e.getSource()==b6)
        {
            if(opt==1)
                str=String.valueOf(resultat.getText())+6;
            else
                str=String.valueOf(" ")+6;
            opt=1;
            resultat.setText(str);
        }
        //Action Corresponding to 7 button
        else if(e.getSource()==b7)
        {
            if(opt==1)
                str=String.valueOf(resultat.getText())+7;
            else
                str=String.valueOf(" ")+7;
            opt=1;
            resultat.setText(str);
        }
        //Action Corresponding to 8 button
        else if(e.getSource()==b8)
        {
            if(opt==1)
                str=String.valueOf(resultat.getText())+8;
            else
                str=String.valueOf(" ")+8;
            opt=1;
            resultat.setText(str);
        }
        //Action Corresponding to 9 button
        else if(e.getSource()==b9)
        {
            if(opt==1)
                str=String.valueOf(resultat.getText())+9;
            else
                str=String.valueOf(" ")+9;
            opt=1;
            resultat.setText(str);
        }
        //Action Corresponding to BACKSPACE button
        else if(e.getSource()==efface)
        {
            int len;
            str=resultat.getText();
            len=str.length();
            if(len>=1)
                str=str.substring(0,len-1);
            resultat.setText(str);
        }
        //Action Corresponding to CE button
        else if(e.getSource()==ce)
        {
            result=0;
            first=1;
            opt=2;
            str=String.valueOf('0');
            resultat.setText(str);

        }
        //Action Corresponding to C button
        else if(e.getSource()==c)
        {
            result=0;
            memory=0;
            first=1;
            opt=2;
            resultat.setText("0");


        }
        //Action Corresponding to . button
        else if(e.getSource()==virgule)
        {
            str=String.valueOf(resultat.getText())+".";
            resultat.setText(str); 
        }
        //Action Corresponding to 1/x button
        else if(e.getSource()==unsurx)
        {
            double n1=Double.parseDouble(resultat.getText());
            n1=1/n1;
            str=String.valueOf(n1);
            resultat.setText(str); 
        }
        //Action Corresponding to sqrt button
        else if(e.getSource()==carre)
        {
            double n1=Double.parseDouble(resultat.getText());
            n1=Math.sqrt(n1);
            str=String.valueOf(n1);
            resultat.setText(str);
        }
        //Action Corresponding to % button
        else if(e.getSource()==percent)
        {
            double n1=Double.parseDouble(resultat.getText());
            n1=(n1*num)/100;
            str=String.valueOf(n1);
            resultat.setText(str);
        }

        else if (e.getSource()==calculer){


            Date date1 = null;
            Date date2 = null;

            int nbSemaines = 0;
            int nbAnnees = 0;
            long nbJours = 0;
            long UNE_HEURE = 60 * 60 * 1000L;
            date1 = (Date) datePicker1.getDate();
            date2 = (Date) datePicker2.getDate();


            long nbj = (date2.getTime() - date1.getTime() + UNE_HEURE) / (UNE_HEURE * 24);


            textdif.setText(nbAnnees +" années; "+ nbSemaines+" semaines; "+ nbJours+" jours"); 
            textdifj.setText(nbj+" jours");



        }

        else if(e.getSource()==apropos){  new Apropos(); }
        else if(e.getSource()==fermer){ System.exit(0);} 
        else if (e.getSource()==inv){

            if (inv.getModel().isSelected()){
                panel2.remove(intt); panel2.remove(ln); panel2.remove(sin); panel2.remove(sinh);
                panel2.remove(dms); panel2.remove(cosh);   panel2.remove(cos);   panel2.remove(pi);
                panel2.remove(tanh);   panel2.remove(tan);
                panel2.validate();

                coordonne(0,3,gbc,1,1);
                panel2.add(frac,gbc);

                coordonne(1,3,gbc,1,1);
                panel2.add(sinhun,gbc);

                coordonne(2,3,gbc,1,1);
                panel2.add(sinmun,gbc);

                coordonne(0,4,gbc,1,1);
                panel2.add(deg,gbc);

                coordonne(1,4,gbc,1,1);
                panel2.add(coshun,gbc);

                coordonne(2,4,gbc,1,1);
                panel2.add(cosun,gbc);

                coordonne(0,5,gbc,1,1);
                panel2.add(deuxpi,gbc);

                coordonne(1,5,gbc,1,1);
                panel2.add(tanhun,gbc);

                coordonne(2,5,gbc,1,1);
                panel2.add(tanun,gbc);

                coordonne(2,2,gbc,1,1);
                panel2.add(ex,gbc);
                panel2.validate();}
            else { 
                panel2.remove(frac);
                panel2.remove(sinhun);
                panel2.remove(sinmun);
                panel2.remove(deg); 
                panel2.remove(coshun);
                panel2.remove(cosun);
                panel2.remove(deuxpi);
                panel2.remove(tanhun);
                panel2.remove(tanun);
                panel2.remove(ex);
                panel2.validate();

                coordonne(0,3,gbc,1,1);
                panel2.add(intt,gbc);

                coordonne(1,3,gbc,1,1);
                panel2.add(sinh,gbc);

                coordonne(2,3,gbc,1,1);
                panel2.add(sin,gbc);

                coordonne(0,4,gbc,1,1);
                panel2.add(dms,gbc);

                coordonne(1,4,gbc,1,1);
                panel2.add(cosh,gbc);

                coordonne(2,4,gbc,1,1);
                panel2.add(cos,gbc);

                coordonne(0,5,gbc,1,1);
                panel2.add(pi,gbc);

                coordonne(1,5,gbc,1,1);
                panel2.add(tanh,gbc);

                coordonne(2,5,gbc,1,1);
                panel2.add(tan,gbc);

                coordonne(2,2,gbc,1,1);
                panel2.add(ln,gbc);
                panel2.validate();
            }

        }

    }

    /////// Operations

    void add1()
    {
        if(first==0)
            result=num=result+n1;
        String str=String.valueOf(result);
        resultat.setText(str);
        opt=2;
        if(oper2!=0)
        {
            oper1=oper2;
            oper2=0;
        }
        first=0;
    }
    //Sub called according to previous operator
    void sub()
    {
        if(first==0)
            result=num=result-n1;
        String str=String.valueOf(result);
        resultat.setText(str);
        opt=2;
        if(oper2!=0)
            oper1=oper2;
        first=0;
    }
    //Div called according to previous operator
    void div()
    {
        if(first==0)
        {
            if(n1==0)
                resultat.setText("Cannot divide by zero");
            else
                result=num=result/n1;
        }
        String str=String.valueOf(result);
        resultat.setText(str);
        opt=2;
        if(oper2!=0)
            oper1=oper2;
        first=0;
    }
    //Mul called according to previous operator
    void mul()
    {
        if(first==0)
            result=num=result*n1;
        String str=String.valueOf(result);
        resultat.setText(str);
        opt=2;
        if(oper2!=0)
            oper1=oper2;
        first=0;
    }



}
```

Comment: *"What is the reason of this issue?"*  (Most probably) the code.  For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example).

Comment: the code is all correct and i have over 1000 lines. if it's because the code then why it is sometimes showing ?

Comment: I can almost guarantee you that it is your code at fault. Computers don't have a mind of their own. Please post your code.

Comment: comment out / or disable parts of your code, until the problem does not appear again. That way you can find at what point the problem is. Then you can post that code (without posting the 10000 lines)

Comment: `"the code is all correct and i have over 1000 lines."` -- Seriously? How on earth can you assume this when the program is obviously misbehaving? Time to do some debugging.

Comment: @SanjayManohar  Kindly check the  code ,and try it in your machine if possible

Comment: That is not MCVE. And... using `==` to compare objects does not bode well for your `the code is all correct` statement.

Comment: 1) `public static void main(String[] args) { new Calculette(); }`  Swing GUIs should be created and updated on the EDT.  See the [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) lesson of the tutorial for details. 2) Call `pack()` after all the components are added.

Comment: 3) `if (list.getSelectedIndex()==0 ){ panel3.remove(dee); ..`  Use a `CardLayout`..  -- I'm more surprised this code ever worked, than that it now fails!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling `setVisible(true)` at the beginning of your constructor **before** adding components to the JFrame, and so you're displaying the GUI before all components are added. Don't do this, call this method at the end of your constructor, or at the completion of your adding all components to the GUI.

And again, never make this assumption, `""the code is all correct..."` -- especially in a large misbehaving program of > 1000 lines. I know -- Every time I've done this, I've ended up looking foolish and so have learned my lesson.

Also, you're swapping a lot of components in your code and should consider using a [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) to help you do this swapping in a cleaner and easier fashion.

Comment: Thank you. This is the reason of the issue

Comment: @Souad: and thanks for ultimately showing your code. Also please see link and suggestion about using CardLayout.

Comment: Also change the main method; you are construction the UI on the main thread, which can cause spurious irregular problems. Use (for example) SwingUtilities.invokLater(Runnable) to create the UI on the event dispatch thread.